# How to layout elements side by side on a Linear Layout and apply proper spacing and alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having problem with layout of a Linear layout with elements that are side by side together.
I can make them go side by side within a Linear layout by putting the elements inside a TableView but I cannot apply proper alignment to them.
e.g. the TextView1 must be align left and its partner TextView2 is align right
Even the Button wont align Right even if I use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

I am trying to create a receipt activity where the caption "SubTotal", "tax","Total" are aligned to the left and their values aligned to the right
Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:elevation=".5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="SAN AGUSTIN MUSEUM"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTicketName"/>
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="(Comes with Audio Guide)"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTicketDesc"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">



        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TblText1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Subtotal:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TblText11"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="$5.00"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Subtotal $5.00"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTicketName"

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textSubtotal"/>




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Tax $0.50"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTicketName"

            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/textTax"/>

        <View android:background="#000" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="1px"/>

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Total $5.50"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTotal"

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTotalAmount"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" PURCHASE "
        android:id="@+id/hiaButton"
        android:onClick="hiaGetTicket"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:alpha="20"

        android:background="@drawable/buttonround"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is what I am aiming for.  In the xml there are 2 subtotal textfields because I was trying out the TablView.
It must be side by side but the caption on the right side is justified right while the values on the right side is justified right also

[image]

**So far this is whats happening
using the xml below**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a grid view?

Comment: Adding an image/template of your expected result can be helpful. Also linearLayout doesn't support layout_alignParentRight.

Comment: @Malith Nope can you provide an example as an answer? I have tried using different layouts within layouts with horizontal orientation and others but not grid

Comment: @Ozgur I have added an image of my desired layout just now.  Thank you :)

Comment: I would use a RelativeLayout. In that way you will be able to use layout_alignParentRight. The only drawback is that you need to be careful with the actual relations between the views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use layout_weight to create a space between two views.

```
<!-- Subtotal row -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
orientation:"horizontal">

  <!--txt-->
  <TextView
  android:layout_width="120dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Subtotal"
  android:gravity="right"
  />

  <!-- empty space that will fill "subtotal" and "price", using layout_weight -->
  <View 
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_height="1dp"/>

  <!-- price -->
  <TextView
  android:layout_width="20dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Subtotal"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

layout_weight allows us to organize child views based on their "weight"s. Look at those examples:

**1. Example**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
orientation:"horizontal"
android:weightSum="300" --> total sum of child's weight
>

<Button 
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="100" -> %33
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:text="Button1"
/>

<Button 
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="100" -> %33
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:text="Button2"
/>

<Button 
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_weight="100" -> %33
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:text="Button3"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Preview:

<kbd>____Button1____</kbd><kbd>____Button2____</kbd><kbd>____Button3____</kbd> (equal widths, and there will be %1 space)

**2. Example**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
orientation:"horizontal"
android:weightSum="80" --> total sum of child's weight
>

<Button 
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="40" -> %50
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:text="Button1"
/>

<Button 
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="20" -> %25
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:text="Button2"
/>

<Button 
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_weight="20" -> %25
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:text="Button3"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Preview:

<kbd>________Button1________</kbd><kbd>____Button2____</kbd><kbd>____Button3____</kbd> (first one is wider)

**3. Example, your case**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
orientation:"horizontal">

  <!--txt-->
  <TextView
  android:layout_width="120dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Subtotal"
  android:gravity="right"
  />

  <View 
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="777" --> this will fill empty space, we didn't specify weightSum, so it thinks weightSum is 777.
  android:layout_height="5dp"
  android:background="#ff0000"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It actually worked but not after experimenting with different dp values for the first and 2nd text element until they fit in a single row.  
I dont fully understand how the layout_weight="1" worked and why the 1 is the correct value to put for the weight

Comment: Thanks  now its also a nice reference for others.  I accepted your answer just now :)

Answer (score 4):

With Relative Layout you can do it by this way,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firsttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And if you want to do with LinearLayout you need to use weightsum and weight for textview.